# DocuSign REST API, change account's email address? (ie, the users login name)

Tags: docusignapi

At my company, we are implementing some parts of DocuSign, and have run across a scenario we believe the REST API does not support.

There are times where user's in our system change email addresses.  We want to push this change to DocuSign for the user, without the user ever requiring to log in to DocuSign and manually change their email address via the console.  This, of course, changes the username the user authenticates with on the login page of DocuSign.

Is it possible, using the DocuSign REST API, to change a user's email address (which in effect changes their login name do DocuSign)?

Comment: I believe you are correct -- changing a user's email address via the REST API is not supported.

Comment: You are both correct! I also do not believe this will ever be available due to security reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DocuSign system does not support changing the email address through the API (REST or SOAP).  This is mainly due to security restrictions - unfortunately your users will need to manually go into the DocuSign Console and go to `Preferences` to change their email address.

One thing that might make this process a little smoother is to automatically open the Console for your users when they request to change their email address.  You can open the Console in an embedded iFrame in your site or app and from there they can change their account info.  You would just need the user's credentials (along with the integrator key of the integration) and you can open the console for them.

The third API Walkthrough - [Embedded DocuSign Console](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedDocuSign)  - illustrates exactly how to do this in 6 different languages (`PHP`, `Java`, `Javascript`, `Python`, `C#`, and `Objective-C`).  You just need to make the following call from your environment, with just your `accountId` in the body of the POST request:

Method

```
POST
```

URI

```
/accounts/{accountId}/views/console
```

BODY

```
{ 
    "accountId": "XXXXXX"
}
```