# DocuSign REST API, easily move envelope from user A to user B? (ie, change the envelope owner)

Tags: docusignapi

A followup to a question answered here regarding changing the email address of a user via the REST API:

[DocuSign REST API, change account's email address? (ie, the users login name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101309/docusign-rest-api-change-accounts-email-address-ie-the-users-login-name)

If, instead, we created a second docusign user login with a new email address and wanted to move all envelopes from the old user to the new user, what is the most efficient way to do this?  Both users would be under the same parent docusign account.

Currently, I do not see an endpoint to move an envelope between users.

Does this entail downloading all envelopes, and then sending on behalf of them all (from parent to child account) to put the documents into the newly created user's account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, I see that the error **ENVELOPE_TRANSFEREE_ALREADY_OWNS_ENVELOPE** is documented in the REST API guide (https://08d1d92f490618f41c65-8fb00e97ac499a7066a18ce9c66b019b.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf), but yet the guide contains no obvious documentation of a related REST API operation (i.e., one that would enable you to transfer ownership of an envelope).

With the SOAP API, you can use the **TransferEnvelope** operation (page 178: https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/soap-api-guide.pdf) to transfer an envelope from one user to another.

Based on the fact that "**TransferEnvelope**" is missing from this list of all SOAP API operations that are supported in the REST API, I'd suspect that Transferring Envelopes isn't (yet) supported via the REST API:

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#Appendix/DocuSign API to REST API.htm