# Transfer Envelope Between DocuSign Users

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to transfer envelope ownership between two DocuSign users within the same account?  Say for example an employee leaves the company.  I'd like to use the REST services to transfer those envelopes to another employee.  I have not seen an an endpoint that would facilitate this functionality.

Found this thread from a year ago that talked about the same need :
[DocuSign REST API, easily move envelope from user A to user B? (ie, change the envelope owner)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142446/docusign-rest-api-easily-move-envelope-from-user-a-to-user-b-ie-change-the-e)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Things are still the same with regards to the thread you referenced - there's a call to transfer ownership in the SOAP API but not the REST API, unfortunately.

Here's the call in the SOAP API (see page 178: https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/soap-api-guide.pdf) to transfer an envelope from one account user to another.