# Transfer Envelopes between users in docuSign

Tags: c#, rest, docusignapi

Is it possible to transfer onwership of an envelope between two users within the same account through c# DocuSign SDK or REST API.

Found these posts but they are 4 and 5 years old.

[Transfer Envelope Between DocuSign Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34074459/transfer-envelope-between-docusign-users)

[DocuSign REST API, easily move envelope from user A to user B? (ie, change the envelope owner)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142446/docusign-rest-api-easily-move-envelope-from-user-a-to-user-b-ie-change-the-e)

Wanted to know if there are any updates ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are old posts because this is only possible with our older SOAP API. The newer, modern REST API does not have this functionality.
If you must have this in your app - you will need to use the SOAP API and these old threads are still valid.

Comment: thanks !!! @Inbar Gazit. May I know if this will be implemented in the REST API sooner ?

Comment: I have no information about that, so I guess the answer is "no". Sorry.

Comment: There's an open Enhancement Request for this functionality. If you'd like to show interest, reach out to your account team to request they add your info to EC-1549.