# RestAPI "create" envelope where the envelope belongs to a different user than the API user?

Tags: docusignapi

I want to make an API call to "create" an envelope:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/

but where the envelope belongs to a different user than the API caller.

Right now, when a DocuSign envelope is created, they all show up in Manage/Drafts of the API user...but I'd like to control which user they go to, so a user like `name@example.com` can log into their DocuSign account and have that envelope show up in their drafts. I want to do this programmatically instead of clicking around a UI every time.

We have our DocuSign integration through Intelledox, and in their Infiniti Design, we have different hooks set up (create/post/send email) and their UI dropdowns for Action Input have a lot of different actions one can do....but there's no "Assign Envelope Owner" or anything like that...hence me digging through the API to see what can be done.

I saw a question like this over at [DocuSign REST API, easily move envelope from user A to user B? (ie, change the envelope owner)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142446/docusign-rest-api-easily-move-envelope-from-user-a-to-user-b-ie-change-the-e) but it was 6 years ago and wasn't sure if this ever got moved to "possible".

Comment: how is your integration authenticating into DocuSign?

Comment: Authentication into DocuSign is through Intelledox InfinitiMange Settings-> DocuSign, and there's an Admin API Username, Integrator Key, and I see there's a place for an RSA Private Key that says "RSA Private Key Uploaded." I don't have any authentication issues...I sense this transfer user feature is just not supported in DocuSign's REST Api. Hopefully I'm wrong on that one.

Comment: so, this is using JWT. The "Admin API Username" is what you can change to change the user. It doesn't technically have to be an admin, unless this integration (which Im not sure what it does exactly) requires it. This is not really a question for stackveroflow as you're not developing using the API, I would ask the Intelledox customer support.

Comment: Well, the idea is that I try a proof-of-concept that I can do this with the API. I guess I'll just flat out ask - does the API support this, or is this yet another instance of this question? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57715790/transfer-envelopes-between-users-in-docusign?rq=1

Comment: not sure what "this" is, the API supports using different users as well as changing them, as long as you obtain a new token. the API also supports looking up users and their IDs.

Comment: So you're saying the API supports changing the user of an envelope? That's what I'm after, at least as a first step. I didn't see anything in the DocuSign REST API docs that address this.

Comment: if you mean custody transfer of an envelope - no, can't do that with the REST API. Not sure that's what you meant.

Comment: you can do that with the old SOAP API

Answer (score 0):

If your objective is that you need other users to see the envelope, then you simply share the user's envelopes with other users. That way, one does not have to login with the API user in DS to see the envelopes. If you want the envelope being sent to appear to a different user other than the API user, try using custody transfer feature in DS. however this will be limiting to only one user. Else, I do not thing there is any other way, May be you can check with IX support on that.

Comment: Yeah, the problem with sharing is, you have to click around in the DocuSign GUI to do these things, and I'm looking to have this happen programmatically in an automated API call right after an envelope is generated, so people using our Intelledox and DocuSign at our company aren't having to manually go to each envelope on the website and "share" it, or do a custody transfer.

Comment: sharing and custody transfer are not the same. Which one do you want to do?

Comment: if an envelope is a car - sharing means you let your friend drive it.
Custody transfer means you sell your car to your friend and the friend gets to be the owner of the car.

Comment: What I'm wanting to do is perform whatever action needs to happen to an envelope so that when a DocuSign user logs into their account, the envelope that was created and sent to them shows up in their Manage/Drafts, instead of showing up in the Manage/Drafts of the API User (which is what I'm currently observing). Reading the docs and the other stackoverflow questions on this, my impression is that the action that needs to happen is the envelope needs to be transferred to a different owner - whatever that's called. It looks like this is a SOAP API action that I can't do with REST.

Comment: @Mark Did you ever figure this out?